# Possible to have one config file for javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have some host-specific values I keep various config files for but now I need some of their values in my javascript code.  How can I have one config for both javascript and php?

The information in the config should be private if possible as it contains host/database credentials.

Comment: If all of your config values are contained in an Object, and that config is okay to be publicly disclosed, you could just do `<script>var config = <?php echo json_encode($config); ?>;</script>`

Comment: This question is far too broad. You might be able to find a format both languages understand (like JSON), but the setup depends on how your applications are designed.

Comment: More context would be nice. Keep in mind that PHP runs on the server, while Javascript runs on the client.

Comment: I don't get what's unclear about it.  I want to have a file containing variables I can access with both my javascript and php files.  Is this possible?

Comment: If this is unclear maybe you guys have reading comprehension issues...

Comment: edit: actually nevermind. this is not how you get help

Comment: Basically I have a script that copies the appropriate credentials to `config.php` from, say, for example `config.php.host-gator` then uploads it.  But I have a function in my javascript code that does url creation and needs to have the domain to create it, so it would be very convenient to have the one config file contain this info and be included in the js file as well.

Comment: And I'd just like to add that the programming community is among the most toxic I have ever been a part of.  I love programming and improving but I feel as much affinity for the community as I do a herpes blister.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your configuration is contained in an object you can fully disclose, you can simply do:

```
<script>var config = <?php echo json_encode($config); ?>;</script>
```

But if you only want/need some of its properties, you could do something like:

```
<script>var host = <?php echo $config["host"]; ?>;</script>
```

or, in a more maintainable way:

```
<?php

$config = array(
    "host" => "http://example.com",
    "items_per_page" => 10,
    "db_password" => "1234"
);
// Properties you want to include in your JS
$public_properties = array("host", "items_per_page");

// This function returns JSON containing the values from $obj,
// but only for properties contained in $props
function get_public_json($obj, $props) {
    $res = array();
    foreach($props as $prop)
    {
        $res[$prop] = $obj[$prop];
    }
    return json_encode($res);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My website</title>
    <script>
        var config = <?php echo get_public_json($config, $public_properties); ?>;
        // will look like this: {"host" : "http://example.com", "items_per_page" : 10}
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.